# r plotly update button with line plot does not work with add_markers

Tags: r, button, plotly, line, updates

I have a problem with the joined plot of an updatable line and static markers in R plotly. The line plot is updated via a drop down menu button, which works well on its own. The additional dots in the add_markers function are also correct when the plot is first initialized.

But **after the first update**, the markers are cut off (to the left side of the plot where the line starts) and remaining markers are modified (y values are different to initial ones).

For the example here the button function is simplified, but the result shows the same strange behavior.

`

```
sample_df <- tibble::tibble(quarter_date = rep(c("2022-06-30","2022-09-30","2022-12-31"),3),
               forecast_value = runif(9,min = 10,max = 16),
               forecast_date = c(rep("2022-07-23",3),rep("2022-08-26",3),rep("2022-09-15",3)))

marks = tibble::tibble(dates = c("2022-05-21","2022-06-15","2022-07-02","2022-07-26","2022-08-27"),
                       values = c(11,13,12,15,14))

create_buttons <- function(df, date_id) {
  lapply(
    date_id,
    FUN = function(date_id,df) {
      button <- list(
        method = 'restyle',
        args = list('y', list(df %>% 
                                dplyr::filter(forecast_date == date_id) %>% 
                                dplyr::pull(forecast_value))),
        label = sprintf('Forecast @ %s', date_id)
      )
    },
    df
  )
}


plotly::plot_ly(x = ~quarter_date)  %>% 
  plotly::add_trace(data = sample_df %>% 
                      dplyr::filter(forecast_date == max(forecast_date)),
                    #x = ~period_date, 
                    y = ~forecast_value,
                    type = 'scatter',
                    mode = 'markers+lines',
                    name = 'forecasts')  %>%
  plotly::layout(
    title = "Drop down menue",
    yaxis = list(title = "y"),
    updatemenus = list(
      list(
        y =1,
        x = 0.9,
        buttons = create_buttons(sample_df, unique(sample_df$forecast_date))
      )
    )) %>% 
  plotly::add_markers(data = marks,
                      x = ~dates,
                      y = ~values)
```

`

I have tried to set a wide xrange, used a second y2 axis and different approaches in the button calculation but nothing works as intended.

Does anyone have a clue why the add_markers is not working correctly after updating the line plot? Any ideas are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding markers aren't the issue. The issue comes from the restyle. When you `restyle` the plot without designating that you only meant to change one trace, you changed all traces.

The solution is actually quite simple, you just need one more argument in your `args` call-- the trace number in a list: `list(0)` in this case. I've commented out your original `args` call, so you can see the change.

> To make this repeatable, I added `set.seed(46)` before the creation of `sample_df`.

```
create_buttons <- function(df, date_id) {
  lapply(
    date_id,
    FUN = function(date_id, df) {
      button <- list(
        method = 'restyle',
        args = list('y', list(df %>% filter(forecast_date == date_id) %>% 
                                pull(forecast_value)), list(0)),
        # args = list('y', list(df %>% 
        #                         filter(forecast_date == date_id) %>% 
        #                         pull(forecast_value))),
        label = sprintf('Forecast @ %s', date_id)
      )
    },
    df
  )
}
```

Now when you run your plot, you will see that your marker data remains visible.

[image]

[image]